# cant replace data in serialized textview, bytearray size problem?

Tags: python, serialization, replace, encoding, gtk

Im really struggling with serialized textbuffer data.  I just got thru an SQL encoding issue(thanks theGtkNerd for the help.) and now my troubles are back.
Im trying to add search/replace functionality to a textview that is using pixbufs and formated text, since i have images/tags stored in the buffer, i am trying to do the replace on the serialized textview buffer data.
  the following code works as long as the replace string is the same size as the searchstr.

```
def _diagFnRReplaceAll(self,oWidget): #Replace All Function
    findbox = self.builder.get_object('FnRFindEntry')
    searchstr = findbox.get_text()
    buf = self.dataview.get_buffer()
    repbox = self.builder.get_object('FnRReplaceEntry')
    repstr = repbox.get_text()
    format = buf.register_serialize_tagset()

    data = buf.serialize(buf, format, buf.get_start_iter(),
    buf.get_end_iter())

    sys.stdout.buffer.write(data) #< print raw for debugging
    newdata = data.replace(bytes(searchstr,'ascii'),bytes(repstr,'ascii'))
    print("\n\n\n\n")
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(newdata) #< print raw for debugging

    buf.set_text('')
    format = buf.register_deserialize_tagset()
    buf.deserialize(buf, format, buf.get_end_iter(),newdata)
```

if its smaller or larger i get the following error.

```
Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtktextbufferserialize.c:1588:text_handler: code should not be reached
```

i tried changing the encoding type, and different ways to encode, but it didnt help. the fact that a same size string works fine makes me think there is a size value for the serialized buffer data or pixbuf data somewhere, but i havnt come up with anything by searching.
i tried to do the replace like you would on a textview without pics, it worked but lost the pic/format data.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

or does anyone know another way i can do a search and replace in a textview widget that has pixbuf data and formatting tags?

Comment: i think im making a little progress. it looks like the size of the array may be stored right in the contents of the buffer.  here is the start line of the buffer:     GTKTEXTBUFFERCONTENTS-0001L <text_view_markup>     the L right after the 0001 changes with size.  im going to experiment with modifying that and see what happens

Comment: If I remember right, I had this problem when I used iters for searching. I replaced iter usage with marks. Let me see if I can find my code again.

Comment: Hopefully [this](https://github.com/benreu/gremlin/blob/4c8410f3b7d7aea1b8f8a5f00d36201ccccd7405/src/gremlin.py#L141) helps. Iters get [invalid](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktextbuffer.html#method-gtktextbuffer--insert) after changing the buffer contents, therefore you need to use marks.

Answer (score 0):

well i got it wotking using a little byte patching.I just saw your comment on using marks, i will look into that as i would rather use builtin functionality instead of what im doing.  My way is replacing the 4 bytes after the GTKBUFFERCONTENTS-001 with a new 4 byte value for the new size of the buffer. 
here is what i have working right now

```
def _diagFnRReplaceAll(self,oWidget):
    findbox = self.builder.get_object('FnRFindEntry')
    searchstr = findbox.get_text()
    buf = self.dataview.get_buffer()
    repbox = self.builder.get_object('FnRReplaceEntry')
    repstr = repbox.get_text()
    format = buf.register_serialize_tagset()
    data = buf.serialize(buf, format, buf.get_start_iter(), buf.get_end_iter())



    start_bytes = data[0:26]
    size_bytes =data[26:30]
    sizeval = int.from_bytes(size_bytes, byteorder='big', signed=False)

    end_of_markup = 29 + sizeval +1 
    the_rest = data[end_of_markup:len(data)]
    markup = data[30:end_of_markup]

    newmarkup = bytearray(markup.replace(bytes(searchstr,'ascii'),bytes(repstr,'ascii')))

    newsize = len(newmarkup).to_bytes(4,'big')

    reconstruct =start_bytes + newsize + newmarkup +the_rest


    buf.set_text('')
    format = buf.register_deserialize_tagset()
    buf.deserialize(buf, format, buf.get_end_iter(),reconstruct)
```

This works without issue so far, i will repost if i get it working with the 'Marks' suggestion.   Thanks again theGtknerd.